# How to modify a core theme and what is the correct way to do this?

Tags: 7, theming

I modified the core's Bartik theme file, node.tpl.php.  I simply added

```
echo "Last updated by $name on " . format_date($node->changed);
```

The problem is that when there is a new core update, my change will be overwritten.  Is there a way to create a module that will easily add this simple line in the node.tpl.php of Bartik's node.tpl.php theme file so that future updates will not overwrite my change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want to do is [create a subtheme of Bartik](http://opensourcecms.pro/drupal/howto-drupal-7-sub-theme-creation-step-by-step/), and make your modifications to node.tpl.php there instead. Themes support the notion of inheritance, so this can be leveraged to tweak core themes without actually hacking core. As a rule, [it is best practice not to hack core](http://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core) for the reasons you mentioned and a slew of others, security not the least among them.

Comment: Thanks, this got me 95% of the way there.  Unfortunately I am not able to use the color picker preview to change my theme's colors.  It only works if I start to copy over the Bartik 'color' and 'css' folders.  This means I am essentially just copying file for file Bartik's code, which I don't want to do.  I just want to overwrite that one file. Nonetheless, without copying over the 'color' and 'css' folder, my node.tpl.php is overriding Bartik's node.tpl.php, which is good enough for me.  I will hand set my colors or do custom CSS.